# System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled. after connect 8th Device

Tags: asp.net-core

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at ecapture.local.api.Helpers.RTCClient.SendMsg(String endpoint, String jsonContent, String excludeConnectionId, String receiverConnectionId) in C:\projects\ecapture\ecapture.local.api\Helpers\RTCClient.cs:line 128
```

I have two projects one is in .net core 3.0 and another is in .net core 2.1. 
I connect the iPad device with the 2.1 project using SignalR. One API is called from  2.1 to 3.0 
which saves iPad details and in the same request I called another API 3.0 to 2.1.

I am able to connect 8 devices successfully in a development environment.

but when I deployed these two projects on the IIS server upto 7 iPad devices is connected when I try to connect
8th device and called API from 3.0 to 2.1. I am facing the above issue.

but no luck.

I have already tried this.

1. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/httpclientfactory-vs-httpclient-to-implement-api-calls/
2. private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(); (Singleton pattern)

Comment: Do you know from where you are getting this very exception? Did you had the chance to debug the relevant code snippet or stacktrace? It would be great if you could share more details or troublesome code snippet or even, share minimal reproducible sample in order to investigate details on the issue.